# Transposing Data SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

The data looks similar to this:

```
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+--------+
| ID | Unit | Floorplan | Sq Ft |  Name   | Amenity | Charge |
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+--------+
|  1 |  110 | A1        |   750 |  Alan   | GARAGE  |     50 |
|  2 |      |           |       |         | RENT    |    850 |
|  3 |      |           |       |         | PEST    |      2 |
|  4 |      |           |       |         | TRASH   |     15 |
|  5 |      |           |       |         | TOTAL   |     20 |
|  6 |  111 | A2        |   760 |  Bill   | STORAGE |     35 |
|  7 |      |           |       |         | GARAGE  |     50 |
|  8 |      |           |       |         | RENT    |    850 |
|  9 |      |           |       |         | PEST    |      2 |
| 10 |      |           |       |         | TOTAL   |     15 |
| 11 |  112 | A3        |   770 | Charlie | PETRENT |     20 |
| 12 |      |           |       |         | STORAGE |     35 |
| 13 |      |           |       |         | GARAGE  |     50 |
| 14 |      |           |       |         | RENT    |    850 |
| 15 |      |           |       |         | TOTAL   |      2 |
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+--------+
```

I am new to SQL and trying my best using Microsoft Access, but I need help.

The data needs to look like this:

[image: Ending Picture]

My first step is to separate the units from the rest with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Unit <> NULL;
```

and after that I've usually just hard-input the rest.

My idea was as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table

VALUES (NULL,NULL,...,'Pest',$2)

FROM table

WHERE NOT EXIST 'Pest' BETWEEN x AND y

/* where x = Total 1 and y = Total 2*/
```

Am I on the right track? I probably need a loop or a join, but I'm not at that level yet.

Comment: Your data in your table has all of those blanks? That is supremely awful data. Is the only thing that tells what UNIT something is, if that UNIT is the last non-null UNIT in preceding rows when sorted by ID? Like.. how do you know that rent is 850 for `Alan` using SQL? It'd be nightmarish... perhaps that's why you are asking.

Comment: If you're using MSAccess, it would probably help to tag the question appropriately. MSAccess <> MySQL <> MSSQL <> SQLite <> Oracle....

Comment: Yes my data comes pretty similar to that. A PDF gets converted to Excel, then I try my hand at Access rather than hard-input everything.

Comment: This would be pretty straightforward with a VBA loop over the input recordset, writing into the output recordset. Have you done anything in VBA before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a crosstab query, though a bit convoluted it is:

```
TRANSFORM 
    Sum(TableUnit.Charge) AS SumOfCharge
SELECT 
    S.Unit, 
    S.Floorplan, 
    S.SqFt, 
    S.Name, 
    S.Amenity
FROM 
    TableUnit, 
        (SELECT 
            Q.Id, 
            Val(DMax("Id","TableUnit","Id<=" & Q.[Id] & " And Unit Is Not Null")) AS ParentId
        FROM TableUnit As Q) AS T, 
        (SELECT 
            TableUnit.Id, 
            TableUnit.Unit, 
            TableUnit.Floorplan, 
            TableUnit.SqFt, 
            TableUnit.Name, 
            TableUnit.Amenity
        FROM 
            TableUnit
        WHERE 
            TableUnit.Unit Is Not Null) AS S
WHERE 
    TableUnit.Id=[T].[Id] 
    AND 
    T.ParentId)=[S].[Id]
GROUP BY 
    T.ParentId, 
    S.Unit, 
    S.Floorplan, 
    S.SqFt, 
    S.Name, 
    S.Amenity
PIVOT 
    TableUnit.Amenity In
        ("Garage","Pest","Trash","PetRent","Storage","Rent");
```

Your test data differs a little from your expected output, so:

[image: Output]

Comment: Oh my g-d thank you! Simply amazing how that worked. How do I get to the proficiency you achieved? I've been on SQLZoo.net and SoloLearn.

Comment: You are welcome! First part is to use the _GUI query designer_ - here I started with the subqueries, then cut-paste into the next query until done. Second part is _try and error_ which I've done since 1993 and Access 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

My MSAccess is rather rusty, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT t0.Unit, t0.Floorplan, t0.[Sq Ft], t0.Name, t0.Amenity
   , SUM(IIF(tM.Amenity = 'GARAGE', Charge, 0)) AS [Garage]
   , SUM(IIF(tM.Amenity = 'PEST', Charge, 0)) AS [Pest]
FROM (
   SELECT t1.id AS id0, MIN(t2.id) AS idN
   FROM t AS t1
   INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
   WHERE t1.Unit <> '' AND t2.Unit <> ''
) AS groups
INNER JOIN t AS t0 ON t0.id = groups.id0
LEFT JOIN t AS tM ON tM.id > groups.id0 AND tm.id < groups.idN
GROUP BY t0.Unit, t0.Floorplan, t0.[Sq Ft], t0.Name, t0.Amenity
;
```

Though, if I remember correctly, and it hasn't changed in newer versions; you can't have true subqueries and will need to make `groups` a separate query you can join to as if it were a table/view.